# Multiple masks for phone numbers area code with 2 digits or 3 digits the rest is 7 digits

Tags: jquery

I have input field - phone number that can have 2 formats of phone numbers.

Area code can be with 2 digits or 3 digits and the rest of the number is 7 digits long

Examples:
phone number = "0342356789";
I want to mask it as format: (00) 000-0000

phone number = "052342356789";
I want to mask it as format: (000) 000-0000

Can anyone show me how to use the mask?

Comment: Your second example has 12 digits which is more than 7+3...

Comment: what did you try? should be pretty easy.  all you have to do is check how many digits you have

Comment: Must be nice if those are the only formats you need to deal with. In practice you'll usually encounter a near infinite number of variants.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.1.62/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
jQuery().ready(() => {
   var phones = [{ "mask": "(##)###-####"}, { "mask": "(###)###-####"}];
    jQuery('.phone').inputmask({ 
        mask: phones, 
        greedy: false, 
        definitions: { '#': { validator: "[0-9]", cardinality: 1}} });
});
</script>
<body>


<input type="text" class="phone" />
</body>
</html>
```